# Automatically add "More..." Tab in Android

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I'm writing an application which contains many tabs, and sometimes the number of tabs may exceed five. So I want to make it behave like iPhone, which is, move additional tabs to a "More..." tab. I would like to know if this feature is supported by TabHost, or if there is any existing open source widget which can do the favor for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So I want to make it behave like
>   iPhone, which is, move additional tabs
>   to a "More..." tab. I would like to
>   know if this feature is supported by
>   TabHost

It is not -- sorry!

Answer (score -1):

did you try it or not. that options menu should do the More option automatically when you add more the 6 that i believe. Check this [documentation in developer site](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/menu_design.html)

Comment: As mentioned in the title, summary and tags, this question is about tabs rather than the options menu.